# Best way to make "viewed" attribute for messages inside user group?

Tags: django, django-models, social-networking, django-orm

I am deciding on how to track if a user has seen a post in the timeline or not.

There is `Post` and `Comment` model like this.

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('UserProfile')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    text = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField()

    post = models.ForeignKey('Post', related_name='comments')

class Post(ContentTypeModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    group = models.ForeignKey('UserGroup', null=True)

    date_updated = models.DateTimeField()
```

Suggestions about best practices on how to track if `post` has been seen by particular member of a user `group` will be nice.

Comment: I assume post needs to be seen by group(except comment's author) if new comment is added.

Comment: Add many to many relation with user in your post model then you can filter related users based on their groups with your post model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do as was suggested, i.e. adding m2m relation to track who viewed the post:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField()
    viewers = models.ManyToManyField('UserProfile', through='PostViewer')

class PostViewer(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    viewer = models.ForeignKey('UserProfile', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='posts_seen')

    last_seen = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, help_text='Is set when user sees the post in details')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('post', 'viewer')
```

This way i can compare `post.date_updated` to `viewer.last_seen` and get desired filtering on who have seen the update/create of Post.