# “viewed” attribute in Django Rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I use below solution to check is the user viewed the post or not.

[Best way to make "viewed" attribute for messages inside user group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47982241/best-way-to-make-viewed-attribute-for-messages-inside-user-group/48805260#48805260)

and in django-rest-framework, i create a ListApiView to get all posts:

```
class PostListView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )
    pagination_class = PostListPagination

    def get_queryset(self):

        return Post.objects.filter(state='published').order_by('-created')
```

and the serializers:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields= '__all__'
```

now i want a boolean field named "viewed" for each post in PostListView to show that is the authenticated user viewed this post or not.

something like this:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    viewed = serializers.BooleanField(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields= '__all__'

    def check_is_viewed(current_user, post_instance):
        # if user viewed this post:
        viewed.value = True
        # else:
        viewed.value = False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [MethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield).

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    viewed = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields= '__all__'

    def get_viewed(self, obj):
        return obj.viewers.exist()
```

Comment: how can i get current user object in get_viewed function? i want to search current user id in viewed. in other words, i want to check is the current user viewed the post. or not.

Comment: You would have to pass it using `context`, but only do it when absolutely necessary. This will allow you to make your serializers more reusable:
https://micropyramid.com/blog/django-rest-framework-send-extra-context-data-to-serializers/